# Matching between strings

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have a problem to solve: I have 2 strings and one of those have some "missing words", like the following

```
"This is a 'w1' and it is like 'w2'.
'w1' is known to be 'w3'"
```

where 'w1', 'w2' and 'w3' can be whichever word. Note that in the string above 'w1' appears more than once and it should contain the same word.
Now, the second can be the same as the first but instead of 'w1', 'w2' etc there are words. I need to know if the 2 strings are the same one (replacing in the first string 'w1', 'w2', etc with the words in the second one). I can't figure out how all this can be achived. The second string can even be completely different from the first one and I need to tell those 2 string doesn't match.
maching example:

```
"this is a word1 and it is like word2.
word1 is known to be word3"
```

This string matches the first string.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried a word by word matching approach: with stringTokenizer I get a word from the first string and one from the second and compare them. when i have to compare a "missing word" I just save in an array that w1 = word1 (if the strings are those in the example) and go on like this. So when I find another "missing word" I get from the array if I already assigned a word to that "missing word" and if I already did, I just compare the saved word with the one in the second string. But I was looking for an easier and cleaner way to achive the goal...

Comment: If you know the structure, use `.*` in the pattern where you do not know what to expect. To match `This is a w1 and it is like w2`, use `str.matches("This is a .* and it is like .*")`.

Comment: In the exmple there's 'w1' 2 times in the same string, and that's because it should be replaced with the same word... using " .* " I cant be sure that that is true...

Answer (score 0):

Using this method String.matches(regex) that uses regular expression to match strings?